# Problem with Maxlength validation of jquery

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using the maxlength function of jquery.validate.js plugin to validate for mobile number. as following

txtMobileNo: {

```
            number : true,  
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 12
},
```

and in mysql description of this field is as following...

mobile_no  int(11)

when i enter any valid mobile number it store only this value "2147483647"..

Comment: What do you call "a valid mobile number" ? Depends on your country... In France it's 06XXXXXXXX with numbers as X

Comment: It looks to me like it's storing a valid phone number, do you want jquery to not remove empty spaces or dashes from the phone number?

Comment: i mean if i store any mobile number in indian format like 9555437988, 9873485698 but it store only 2147483647 in database. might be of this Regular expression in jquery.validate.js.



          
         // maxlength may be returned as -1, 2147483647 (IE) and 524288 (safari) for text inputs
  if (rules.maxlength && /-1|2147483647|524288/.test(rules.maxlength)) {
   delete rules.maxlength;
  }
  
  return rules;



        







 Now my question is how could i allow him to store indian formet mobile number???

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like the problem is with your validation, but rather your actual code to store a value in the database. Remove the jQuery validation. Try it again. I bet you still get the same error.

2147483647 is the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer. If you're trying to store 10-12 digit long mobile numbers in a 32-bit signed integer field, you're almost always going to overflow.

You should almost certainly use varchar(12) or something like that for your database representation.

Comment: Thx Carson63000 for rpying. ya it is the problem of overflow. i changed the datatype and now its working fine.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Carson63000, although a phone number is made of numbers, it has no numeric value (for example, try storing a number that starts with a 0), so you should hold the number with its string representation, more specifically, varchar or even char if they have a fixed length.